# Show a notification in the system tray in a standard way

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, air

what is the more **cross-platform** way (**Windows/Linux/iOS**...) for a web application to display some **notifications** in the **system tray** (or equivalent) ?

I guess **HTML + Javascript** won't be sufficient and that I'll need more like some **Flash/Flex/Air**.

But even with **Flex** I'll for sure need to have custom implementations, at least for **iOS**.

So, **what is the right combination of technologies to get a cross-platform notification system** ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For a web app in a browser I'm not sure that's possible. You'll need users to install the app. For windows there's Flash based solutions like AIR, or 3rd party swf wrappers. For iOS if you do not want to code naively you can check our PhoneGap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about PhoneGap. +1